# Select part of a dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R, what I need it is to select the acceleration when the source is equal to 1, and store the data in a variable.

Then do the same for horsepower and relate some histogram or boxplot.

Can you help me?

[image: The dataset]

Comment: What are some of the several ways you tried, and how is this related to statistics and probability?

Comment: What did you try? We can help you with your code but only if you actually show your code. Subsetting is one of the most basic operations in R. You might want to consult a [basic tutorial](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your data is in a data.frame called frame:

```
stored.in.variable <- frame[frame$source == 1,6]
```

Now you'll proceed to draw your histogram/boxplot with this variable. Doing so is left as an exercise to the reader.